# “Offset” function for python index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, offset

I’m a beginner with Python coming from VBA. I’m wondering if there is a way to perform a similar function from vba as range(2,4).offset(5,) within Python? I am finding the iloc of a column and need to move from the found row down x “cells” or index. Not really sure what it’s called in Python yet. I can provide a code snippet once I get back to my computer Monday.

I’m currently using pandas and numpy within a Jupiter notebook.

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: df.iloc[yourfoundindex+5] or look into shift()

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan has mentioned df.iloc[foundindex,column].idxmax()+(neededoffset)) is ultimately what solved my issue. Thanks for the help!